# John Papa angularjs style guide webstorm live templates

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am using Webstorm 2016.1 and trying to configure the templates from John Papa (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y252)
Where exactly do I copy the template xml files?
How do I activate/use them in Webstorm ?

Comment: <home>WebStorm2016.1\config\fileTemplates\ has subdirectories code, includes,internal,j2ee.  is it in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found a way to do it. On a Mac do the following:

- Download [webstorm-angular-live-templates.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/master/a1/assets/webstorm-angular-live-templates/webstorm-angular-live-templates.xml)
- Create a folder in ~/Library/Preferences/WebStorm2016.1 called **templates** if it does not already exist. ([Windows and Linux paths](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/live-templates.html?origin=old_help))
- Move the XML file to the **templates** folder
- Restart WebStorm

To test: In a JavaScript file type `ngcontroller` followed by the Tab key. You should the see the following appear:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('moduleName')
            .controller('ControllerName', ControllerName);

        ControllerName.$inject = ['dependency'];

        /* @ngInject */
        function ControllerName(dependency) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.title = 'ControllerName';

            activate();

            ////////////////

            function activate() {
                code
            }
        }

    })();
```

Comment: **Note for Windows users:** Place the XML file inside `C:/Users/<username>/.WebStorm<version>/config/templates`. If the folder *templates* doesn't already exist, just create it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is when copying the templates above, the "templates" folder does not exist. You'll need to create it like mentioned in the answer above. Dropping the xml in the fileTemplates folder will **not** work.